# My Python script ignores files while copying

Tags: python, copy, shutil

Basically what I want to do in my script is copy some files from dest_path to source_path. You can set it up and see how it works -

But for some reason it copies the first file and tells me that the rest is already copied, which is not true. Is there something that I'm not seeing or that I did wrong? im pretty new to python so sorry if I did something obviously wrong, I just cant see it...

```
import time, shutil, os, datetime

source_path = r"C:\SOURCE"                              # Your Source path
dest_path = r"C:\DESTINATION"                           # Destination path
file_ending = '.txt'                                    # Needed File ending
files = os.listdir(source_path)                         # defines
date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d.%m.%Y')     # get the current date

while True:
    print("Beginning checkup")
    print("=================")
    if not os.path.exists(source_path or dest_path): # checks if directory exists
        print("Destination/Source Path does not exist!")
    else:
        print("Destination exists, checking files...")
        for f in files:
            if f.endswith(file_ending):
                new_path = os.path.join(dest_path, date, )
                src_path = os.path.join(source_path, f)
                if not os.path.exists(new_path): # create the folders if they dont already exists
                    print("copying " + src_path)
                    os.makedirs(new_path)
                    shutil.copy(src_path, new_path)
                else:
                    print( src_path + "  already copied")
                   # shutil.copy(src_path, new_path)

    print("=================")
    print('Checkup done, waiting for next round...')
    time.sleep(10) # wait a few seconds between looking at the directory
```

Comment: `if not os.path.exists(source_path or dest_path):` doesn't do what you think it does. `or` does not work that way.

Comment: also `if not os.path.exists(new_path)` will be checked for each file in `source_path` and only the first file will ever enter this block, since you create the `new_path` inside the first time through

Comment: You see new_path = os.path.join(dest_path, date, ) actually was new_path = os.path.join(dest_path, date, f), but that would create another folder for each file it copied. Thats not what I wanted, so I deleted the f and now it does this. How do I fix this @deppem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @user2357112 mentioned `if not os.path.exists(source_path or dest_path)` is not doing what you think. Change to

```
if not os.path.exists(source_path) or not os.path.exists(dest_path):
```

This will only copy one file because it creates the directory `new_path` the first time through in the `if`. Something like this should work:

```
if f.endswith(file_ending):
    new_path = os.path.join(dest_path, date, )
    src_path = os.path.join(source_path, f)
    if not os.path.exists(new_path): # create the folders if they dont already exists
        os.makedirs(new_path)
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(new_path,f)):
        print("copying " + src_path)
        shutil.copy(src_path, os.path.join(new_path,f))
    else:
        print( src_path + "  already copied")
```

If the `new_path` directory doesn't exist then make the directory (this should only happen once and this `if` could be moved outside of the loop as well as `new_path` initialization). In a separate `if` check if the file exists inside that directory and if not copy the file to the location, else print your message.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much. It does work, thanks for that but I did not fully understand how you solved it. You added another if statement, could you explain it to me so I know what the code is doing? I still have alot of work to do with this script so I want to fully understand what its doing. Hope you understand, and thank again.

Comment: @diatomym let me know if the explanation is enough or if you need more

Comment: Ah so you can also check for files with os.path.join(), right? Thats why I found it confusing, but I think its clear now.